# Synchronous Web Services and page refresh

Tags: java, php, web-services, architecture

I have long running synchronous web service hosted on a Java EE container. I then have a php site that calls the service. What's the proper way of handling a page refresh. I don't want the site to call the web service twice.

As a second question, whose job is it to worry about this? Is it the consumer of the web service or the provider of the service?

Answer (score 0):

If the PHP site calls the web service, in the PHP code or by a AJAX call, it'll get called every time PHP site refreshes (or the AJAX operation is invoked). You could architect around this by using a PHP session to track when you last made a call to the web service.

As to the responsibility, it'd be with whoever is calling the JavaEE service.

One really good way to get around this would be to use a cache engine like memcached to cache the results of the Java web service if the data doesn't need to be "really fresh."